# How to find the API associated with a web application?

Tags: r, socrata

I would like data from this [Center for Disease Control site](https://wonder.cdc.gov/mmwr/mmwrmorb.asp?mmwr_year=1997&mmwr_week=18) of notifiable cases of legionellosis from 1996 to 2016. I have managed to use the RSocrata package and retrieve data for year 2014 to 2016 only using Socrata and and the [Open Data Network](https://www.opendatanetwork.com/search?q=mmwr).

How would I go about retrieving the rest of the information prior 2014?

Here's the code I used for 2014, 2015 and 2016:

```
  #Legionellosis data 

  df.leg2014 <- read.socrata("https://data.cdc.gov/resource/cmap-p7au.json")#2014
  df.leg2015 <- read.socrata("https://data.cdc.gov/resource/haxn-dihy.json") #2015
  df.leg2016 <- read.socrata("https://data.cdc.gov/resource/wg57-d6dj.json") #2016
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like all they've posted to data.cdc.gov is 2014-2016 (https://data.cdc.gov/browse?limitTo=datasets&q=legionellosis&sortBy=relevance&utf8=%E2%9C%93). For the older data you'll have to go through wonder.cdc.gov.

Comment: @chrismetcal Yes, that is where the Wonder app lives that has all my data. I just don't know how to get my data without exporting a file one by one. any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add your own column headers and use this function to loop over your years and weeks. There are some year/week combos that either [return an empty table](https://wonder.cdc.gov/mmwr/mmwr_reps.asp?mmwr_year=1997&mmwr_week=2&mmwr_table=2B&request=Export&mmwr_location=) or where data is [otherwise unavailable](https://wonder.cdc.gov/mmwr/mmwr_reps.asp?mmwr_year=1998&mmwr_week=7&mmwr_table=2B&request=Export&mmwr_location=). It also seems to return different numbers of columns. Some have 12, some have 10. Not sure what's going on. The function has a line to remove columns that are all NA. You may want to comment that line out. I tried to account for that in the code. I didn't test it very well.

```
read_MMWR_table <- function(year=1997, week=18){
  url <- paste0("https://wonder.cdc.gov/mmwr/mmwr_reps.asp?mmwr_year=",
                year, 
                "&mmwr_week=",
                week, 
                "&mmwr_table=2B&request=Export&mmwr_location=")
  tmp <- readLines(url)
  if(grepl("DOCTYPE html", tmp[1])){
    ret <- data.frame()
    print("No table returned, no data...")
  }else{
    start <- which(tmp=="tab delimited data:") + 1
    if(grepl("DOCTYPE html", tmp[1])){
      ret <- data.frame()
      print("No records found for this week / year")
    }else{
      end <- min(which(tmp=="")[which(tmp=="") > 20])
      df <- read.table(textConnection(tmp[start:end]), sep="\t", skip=19, 
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=FALSE)
      # remove all NA cols
      df <- df[,colSums(is.na(df))<nrow(df)]
      ret <- df
    }
  }
  return(ret)
}

df <- read_MMWR_table(year=2001, week=12)
> head(df)
            V1    V2    V3 V4  V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1 W.N. CENTRAL 2,534 3,688 61 102 11  5  2 11  14
2        Minn.   411   723  -   -  1  1  -  8   6
3         Iowa   202   224  -   -  2  2  -  -   -
4          Mo. 1,013 1,803 58  98  5  2  1  3   3
5      N. Dak.     9    11  -   -  -  -  -  -   -
6      S. Dak.    47    61  -   -  -  -  -  -   -
```

Comment: This solution seems similar to what a co-worker attempted that I posted here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616596/requesting-data-from-the-center-for-disease-control-using-rsocrata-or-xml-in-r). However, just like you I was worried about web scraping because the location of legionellosis changes in the table. The headers change so I wanted to see how to avoid web scraping because of the changing headers.

Comment: There's no simple answer here. The data is there, and I've provided a function that gets you 75% of the way. Reading in the headers is fairly trivial, they are listed at the top of each file. You are going to have to put in some work...